# how to build a lazy initializing thread safe wrapper for an object reference

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, synchronized, volatile

I want to implement a wrapper class. The class's only public facing stuff are:

- A constructor that takes logic to create an instance of the wrapped class. Such as `Supplier<WrappedType>`, perhaps.
- A method that gets the instance of the wrapped class.

With the following rule on its behaviour: the logic that creates the wrapped class can have side effects and must only be called once. And, obviously, the getter method should always actually return the same wrapped class instance, which should actually be the result of running the logic that was passed in to the constructor.

I think I have this code that does what I want, but I'm not sure how to test if it is guaranteed to work or not or if there is a better way to do it.

```
package foo;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public final class ConcurrentLazyContainer<A> {
    private Supplier<A> supplier;
    private A value;

    public ConcurrentLazyContainer(Supplier<A> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
        value = null;
    }

    public synchronized A get() {
        if (value == null) {
            value = supplier.get();
            supplier = null;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Does just using `synchronized` get me all the way to what I want here? Do my fields need to be volatile too, perhaps?

I wrote a test that spins up new threads calling the same wrapper but it doesn't appear to me that supplier gets called more than once, which is weird because I don't really understand why volatile wouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: No, you don't need volatile because synchronization creates its own *happens-before* edge.

Comment: My thinking is that the happens-before guarantee means only one thread is executing in `get()`, but this doesn't tell me if the threads are caching `supplier` or `value`. But I also don't really understand Java's memory system, so "uhh stuff might be cached locally in a given thread's memory or something" is about all I understand about what volatile does.

Comment: That's not what happens-before means at all. Happens-before is the guarantee that prevents reordering and caching for volatiles. That guarantee happens to be offered by synchronization as well, in addition to mutual exclusion. So `value` is safe. As far as `supplier`, that depends on how the container is [published](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/), which is a whole other discussion. The simplest way to ensure correctness is to make it `final` and forget the cleanup. Or make it `volatile`.

Comment: Ok, so happens-before is described somewhere in that memory specification, and if my code fulfills its requirements, then threads won't have caching issues that see the wrong value. Supplier can be final, that's no problem. Thanks for the help! If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments on the question are right: if you only access `value` within the `synchronized` method, then you don't need it to be `volatile` as well. However, in some cases, you may be able to improve performance with [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

```
public final class Lazy<T> {

  private final Supplier<? extends T> initializer;
  private volatile T value;

  public Lazy(Supplier<? extends T> initializer) {
    this.initializer = initializer;
  }

  public T get() {
    T result = this.value;
    if (result == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        result = this.value;
        if (result == null) {
          this.value = result = this.initializer.get();
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

}
```

This code is based on some examples shown in *[Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997)* and *[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net)*. Note that this code checks twice to see if `result` is `null`, once outside the `synchronized` block, and once inside. The advantage to this is that you won't need to synchronize if the value already exists. Note that with this strategy, `value` must be `volatile` because it is being accessed outside of the `synchronized` block.